# CraftyJS: I can't destroy an entity with .onHit

Tags: javascript, entity, collision-detection, collision, craftyjs

I am having a problem with craftyJS. I made a ship that shoots lasers, but I want the lasers to destroy an entity when it collides with it. I already tried to do this, but it don't work. Here is my code:

```
Crafty.init(1340,650, document.getElementById('game'));
Crafty.defineScene("gameStart", function() {
function newAlien(){
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
    switch(random){
        case 1:
            var alien = Crafty.e("2D, DOM, Image, Collision")
                .image("alien1.png");
            alien.x = ship.x;
            alien.y = 20
            break;
        case 2:
            var alien = Crafty.e("2D, DOM, Image, Collision")
                .image("alien2.png");
            alien.x = ship.x;
            alien.y = 20;
            break;
        case 3:
            var alien = Crafty.e("2D, DOM, Image, Collision")
                .image("alien3.png");
            alien.x = ship.x;
            alien.y = 20;
            break;
        case 4:
            var alien = Crafty.e("2D, DOM, Image, Collision")
                .image("alien4.png");
            alien.x = ship.x;
            alien.y = 20;
            break;
        }
}
function newLaser(){
    var laser = Crafty.e("2D, DOM, Image, Collision")
    .image("laser.png")
    .collision()
    .onHit("alien", function(){
        laser.destroy();
        alien.destroy();
    });
    laser.y = 510;
    laser.x = ship.x + 40;
    var moveLaser = setInterval(function(){
        if(laser.y < 1){
            clearInterval(moveLaser);
            laser.destroy();
        } else {
            laser.y = laser.y - 4;
        }
    }, 1);
}

function checkBorder(){
    if(ship.x < 0 || ship.x > 1250){
        Crafty.enterScene("gameStart");
    }
}
function goLeft(){
    var goLeftCount = 65;
    var goLeftInterval = setInterval(function(){
        if(goLeftCount === 0){
            clearInterval(goLeftInterval);
            checkBorder();
        } else {
        ship.x = ship.x - 1;
        goLeftCount -= 1;
        }
    }, 1);
}
function goRight(){
    var goRightCount = 65;
    var goRightInterval = setInterval(function(){
        if(goRightCount === 0){
            clearInterval(goRightInterval);
            checkBorder();
        } else {
            ship.x = ship.x + 1;
            goRightCount -= 1;
        }
    }, 1);
}
var ship = Crafty.e("2D, DOM, Image, Bind")
    .image("ship.png")
    .bind('KeyDown', function(e) {
            if(e.key == Crafty.keys['LEFT_ARROW']) {
              goLeft();
              } else if (e.key == Crafty.keys['RIGHT_ARROW']) {
              goRight();
              } else if(e.key == Crafty.keys['SPACE']) {
              newLaser();
              }
          });
ship.y = 520;
ship.x = 600;
newAlien();
});
Crafty.enterScene("gameStart");
```

Can anyone please tell me what are the problems with my code?

Answer (score 0):

One problem: when you try to destroy the alien, the `alien` variable isn't actually in scope.  (You've declared it in a different function.)  So there's no way `alien.destroy();` will work.

Second problem: the function you pass to `.onHit("alien", callback)` will only be run when the laser hits an entity with the "alien" component.  It has no idea what variable name you assigned the entity.  However, the callback function will be passed information about what entities it's colliding with, and you can use that to resolve the collision.